# If I take a loss-compressed file and save it again (e.g. JPEG) will there be loss of quality?

Tags: compression, jpeg, image-formats

I've often wondered, if I load a compressed image file, edit it and the save it again, will it loose some quality? What if I use the same quality grade when saving, will the algorithms somehow detect that the file has already be compressed as a JPEG and therefore there is no point trying to compress the displayed representation again?

Would it be a better idea to always keep the original (say, a PSD) and always make changes to it and then save it as a JPEG or whatever I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) image formats such as [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), successive compression will lead to perceptible quality loss. The quality loss can be in the forms such as [compression artifacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact) and blurriness of the image.

Even if one uses the same quality settings to save an image, there will still be quality loss. The only way to "preserve quality" or better yet, lose as little quality as possible, is to use the highest quality settings that is available. Even then, there is no guarantee that there won't be quality loss.

Yes, it would be a good idea to keep a copy of the original if one is going to make an image using a lossy compression scheme such as JPEG. The original could be saved with a compression scheme which is [lossless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_data_compression) such as [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics), which will preserve the quality of the file at the cost of (generally) larger file size.

(Note: There is a lossless version of JPEG, however, the most common one uses techniques such as [DCT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) to process the image and is lossy.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will lose further file information. If making multiple changes, work off of the original uncompressed file.

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes. However, depending on the compression format there are usually certain operations (mainly rotation and mirroring) that can be performed without any loss of quality by [software](http://jpegclub.org/losslessapps.html) designed to work with the properties of the file format.

Theoretically, since JPEG compresses each 8x8 block pf pixels independantly, it should be possible to keep all unchanged blocks of an image if it is saved with the same compression settings, but I'm not aware of any software that implements this.

Comment: i think acdsee had lossless jpeg rotations but not sure though

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Because level of algorithm used initially will probably be different than in your subsequent saves. You can easily check this by using an Image manipulation software (eg. Photoshop). Save your file several times and change level of of compression each time. Just a slight bit. You'll see image degradation.

Answer (score 1):

If the changes are local (fixing a few pixels, rather than reshading a region) and you use the original editing tool with the same settings, you may avoid degradation in the areas that you do not affect. Still, expect some additional quality loss around the area of change as the compressed blocks are affected, and cannot be recovered.

The real answer remains to carry out editing on the source image, captured without compression where possible, and applying the desired degree of compression before targeting the image for use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will always lose a bit of information when you re-save an image as JPEG. How much you lose depend on what you have done to the image after loading it.

If you keep the image the same size and only make minor changes, you will not lose that much data. When the image is loaded, an approximation of the original image is recreated from the compressed data. If you resave the image using the same compression, most of the data that you lose will be data that was recreated when loading.

If you resize the image, or edit large areas of it, you will lose more data when resaving it. Any edited part of the image will lose about the same amount of information as when you first compressed it.

If you want to get the best possible quality, you should always keep the original.